# Example of a non-convex function that is gradient dominated

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable such that $x^{*}=\text{argmin}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x)$ and gradient dominated, i.e.
\begin{align*}
    f(x) - f(x^{*}) \leq \tau||\nabla f(x)||_{2}^{2}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},
\end{align*}
for some $\tau>0$. Find such a $f$ that is non-convex.

*Remark:* The class gradient dominated functions was originally introduced by Boris Polyak. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06159.pdf), they say that such functions need not be convex.

**Edit:**
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
        x^{2}           & \text{if } x \leq 1,\\
        -\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+3x-\frac{3}{2}           & \text{if } 1 \leq x \leq 2,\\
        x^{2}-3x-\frac{9}{2}           & \text{if } 2 \leq x.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
is such a function with e.g. $\tau=3$.